# How to check if a link exists or not in VC++?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, mfc

I have a link. I have checked that the link is a valid URL through regular expressions. Now, I want to check if the link is a valid http link or not. i.e. it should not be a non-existing link.
Is there a way in VC++ 6.0 (MFC) to check that?

Comment: Do you mean if it actually specifies an up-and-running server and retrieves a resource?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One option is to try to get data from that URL by using the [URLOpenBlockingStream function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms775127%28VS.85%29.aspx).

Example:

```
#include <Urlmon.h>

IStream* pStream = NULL;
if (SUCCEEDED(URLOpenBlockingStream(0, "URL string", &pStream, 0, 0))) {
    // Release the stream immediately since we don't use the data.
    pStream->Release();
    return TRUE;
}
else {
    return FALSE;
}
```

Comment: [URLOpenBlockingStream](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms775127.aspx) has a return value, that should be checked, using [SUCCEEDED](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms687197.aspx) or [FAILED](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms693474.aspx) macro.

Comment: @IInspectable, yes checking the return value is better. I also made the code a bit more readable.

Comment: Error checking is fine, but reading through the documentation, there's nothing in it stating that `pStream` would be `NULL`, if the resource the URL is pointing to does not exist. The web server or ISP might redirect the request to an error page, for example. A solution that actually does work is [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/34686972/1889329).

Comment: @IInspectable, the code tests for *responsive* links. It does not take into account the URL protocol, e.g. http, ftp. Whether this is useful or not depends on the requirements of the application.

Comment: The OP is looking for a way to discern, whether a URL points to an existing resource or doesn't (*"it should not be a non-existing link"*). If you run your code against [https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/000000](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/000000), for example, it will return `TRUE`, even though the URL points to an non-existent resource.

Comment: I think it would be good to add that: one would also need to `#include <winerror.h>` for the `SUCCEDED` macro, `#include <Urlmon.h>` and the last thing (add this last one at the top of your `.cpp` file if you are using header-cpp abstractization) `#pragma comment(lib, "urlmon.lib")`

Comment: @M.Ioan, I added `Urlmon.h`, which will also include the `winerror.h`.