# Unsuccess in using URLOpenBlockingStream to check if online file exists

Tags: c++, winapi

I followed the approach presented here -- [How to check if a link exists or not in VC++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2004419/how-to-check-if-a-link-exists-or-not-in-vc)

and I also tried this code

```
IStream* pStream = NULL;
if (URLOpenBlockingStream(0, sUrl, &pStream, 0, 0) == S_OK)
{
    pStream->Release(); // don't need the data
    return TRUE;
}

return FALSE;
```

I get a TRUE return whether the file exists or doesn't exist.

I'm using URLDownloadToFile successfully so I assume I am linking to the proper library.

Any idea what I am doing wrong or is there an alternate approach?